# Cocoapods installs release rather than master branch of Parse SDK

Tags: ios, git, parse-platform, cocoapods

I am trying to install the master branch of the Parse SDK via cocoapods.  However it continues to install the 1.18 release. I have tried parse repo update and deleting the lock file. Any other suggestions?
My podfile is as follows-

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
use_modular_headers!

def parse_utilities
pod 'Parse/UI', :git => 'https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX.git', :branch => 'master'
pod 'Parse/FacebookUtils', :git => 'https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX.git', :branch => 'master'
end

def parse_framework
pod 'Parse', :git => 'https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX.git', :branch => 'master'
end

target 'BackcountrySkiTracker' do
parse_framework
parse_utilities
pod 'INTULocationManager'
pod 'DKImagePickerController'
pod 'UIImageView-Letters'
end

target 'BCWeatherWidgetExtension' do
parse_framework

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, after deintegrating and installing about two dozen times I was able to pull from the master.